# Can I generate eclipse workspace and project manually/programmatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I need to test JDT/LTK examples, and in order to do so I need to create eclipse workspace and project manually or programmatically.

How can I organize a directory so that I can get valid workspace and project object? I mean, what's special about eclipse workspace and project?

```
IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
// 1. The name of the project in the workspace
IProject project = root.getProject("Hello");
project.open(null /* IProgressMonitor */);

IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);
// 2. The name of the Type (including the namespace)
IType itype = javaProject.findType("smcho.A");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you can create a new IWorkspace from within a running workspace, but you should be able to create a directory and nested projects that can be used as a workspace when you restart Eclipse.

Another approach would be to bring up the Eclipse test environment.  There's a run dialog for that that lets you specify the workspace root directory.  I believe that if you poke around enough you can deduce how to kick that test workspace off (run it) programatically.

Answer (score 1):

The following code dynamically create a Java project with a package and a class. Maybe it is useful for you.

```
// create a project with name "TESTJDT"
IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
IProject project = root.getProject("TESTJDT");
project.create(null);
project.open(null);

//set the Java nature
IProjectDescription description = project.getDescription();
description.setNatureIds(new String[] { JavaCore.NATURE_ID });

//create the project
project.setDescription(description, null);
IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);

//set the build path
IClasspathEntry[] buildPath = {
        JavaCore.newSourceEntry(project.getFullPath().append("src")),
                JavaRuntime.getDefaultJREContainerEntry() };

javaProject.setRawClasspath(buildPath, project.getFullPath().append(
                "bin"), null);

//create folder by using resources package
IFolder folder = project.getFolder("src");
folder.create(true, true, null);

//Add folder to Java element
IPackageFragmentRoot srcFolder = javaProject
                .getPackageFragmentRoot(folder);

//create package fragment
IPackageFragment fragment = srcFolder.createPackageFragment(
        "com.programcreek", true, null);

//init code string and create compilation unit
String str = "package com.programcreek;" + "\n"
    + "public class Test  {" + "\n" + " private String name;"
    + "\n" + "}";

        ICompilationUnit cu = fragment.createCompilationUnit("Test.java", str,
                false, null);

//create a field
IType type = cu.getType("Test");

type.createField("private String age;", null, true, null);
```

Reference: [Creat, Access, Load Projects by using Eclipse JDT](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/05/eclipse-jdt-tutorial-java-model/)